# What is the 'trk: scheme'?

Tags: http, chromium

Reading about [Eloston/ungoogled-chromium](https://github.com/Eloston/ungoogled-chromium), I came across this:

> - (Iridium Browser feature change) Prevent URLs with the trk: scheme from connecting to the Internet
>
>   - Also prevents any URLs with the top-level domain qjz9zk (as used in domain substitution) from attempting a connection.

What is the 'trk: scheme'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the github issue tracker https://github.com/iridium-browser/iridium-browser/issues/55#issuecomment-171953548

> URLs like clients1.google.com/blahblah were replaced by
>   http://trk-123.iridiumbrowser.de/clients1.google.com/blah , so there
>   we would be able to observe, by looking at Apache's access.log, if and
>   when the browser tries a suspicious URL. This suffers from problems:
>   not all developers, let alone users, have a way to access that
>   logfile. So it was replaced in v43 by a client-side-only notification
>   mechanism. URIs now look like
>   "trk:123:http://clients1.google.com/blah" and if the browser tries to
>   load anything from the trk: scheme space, it will show a yellow bar
>   (and continue loading the real URL behind it).

In other words, Iridium will replace requests to third-party trackers and suspicious/malicious urls. It will replace it with the fake "trk:" request, which does nothing. The request to the tracker will fail (*"Prevent[ed] from connecting to the Internet"*). But, you will be able to see what requests were stopped.

Comment: Thank you. Now I'm trying to mark this as answered, but the X (marks the spot) seems to be missing. Oh, it's not an X, it's a check mark. Gah.